# how get a unique Android device ID?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

According to the policy, we must use this method to register the user

Therefore, using email or number to register a user is not a good way for us

According to my studies, there are several ways to get a unique ID

But each has its own problems

I need a method that does not require special access from the user

Using Android ID is a good method. The problem is that it can be changed on rooted phones

And this is very bad in terms of security, of course, in Android lower than 8

Is there a specific trick or method to solve this problem?

I also know an application that does not use Android ID or mac WIFI and Pseudo-Unique ID, but does get the information according to the user's device. Is there a way to know what method it uses?

Comment: Your question contains many mentions of something that is not included in your question: "this method" "several ways" and so on. This make sit hard to answer as large parts are missing.

Comment: _"The problem is that it can be changed on rooted phones"_. Well, Google doesn't want apps to use non-resettable identifiers (such as IMEI), so there's not really a whole lot you can do about that.

Comment: See also https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Answer (score 0):

it's simple all you have to do is use the below code. this method will return android id now all you have to do is add checks at your backend.

```
val id =  Settings.Secure.getString(
          getContext()?.contentResolver,
          Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID
          )
```